# Cache rest api with Azure CDN

Tags: azure, caching, cdn, cqrs, azure-cdn

I've just came across [this article](https://www.fastly.com/blog/api-caching-part-i). It turns out that Fastly's CDN provides support for caching rest api responses. This looks like a perfect solution to relieve your own server and database. Especially if query/command ratio is very high. Basically it works like that:

1. Command (DELETE / POST / PUT) request has to be handled by your server
2. After the command completes your API sends a `purge` request to the CDN
3. In response to the `purge` request CND queries you api for new results and caches it
4. When user queries for a resource the request is handled by the CDN, not bothering your server at all

They provide a configuration interface where you can define caching rules.

Does Azure CDN provide the same kind of functionality? I can't find any information about it on the web.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems like the place that this would live would be in the api management service. According to a discussion at the bottom of [an article about adding caching to improve api performance](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-gb/documentation/articles/api-management-howto-cache/) they seem to say your scenario isn't possible

from the discussion:

"Is it possible to programatically evict something from the cache?"

-- "Currently this is not supported"

Comment: Is it still not recommended to cache REST API responses at CDN? Currently many CDN services provide the option of serving dynamic content.